# uwp xaml DataBinding to nested property inside an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, mvvm, data-binding, uwp-xaml, pivotitem

This is my first time building a UWP app and I'm new to c#/Windows in general. I am trying to use a Pivot in the UI. I want the pivot headers to be from an `ObservableCollection` of usb devices connected, which go by the class `Device_Info`. Each USB Device has a property called `HardwareRevNumMajor` that I would like to display as each pivots header. My xaml looks like this:

```
<Page
x:Class="usb_test.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:usb_test"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:code="using:usb_test"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:View_Model/>
</Page.DataContext>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Pivot x:Name="pivot1" Title="Pivot" Opacity="0.99" ItemsSource="{Binding Devices}">
        <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        <Binding Path="Device_Info.HardwareRevNumMajor"/>
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>

                <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding HardwareRevNumMajor}">
                </TextBlock>-->
            </DataTemplate>
        </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DeviceFiles}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding numBlocks}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding syncTime}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Pivot.ItemTemplate>
    </Pivot>
</Grid>
```

As soon as a `Device_Info` object gets added to the `Devices` observableCollection I get an error. `Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))`. Then if I click in my MainPage.xaml file in the designer I see this:

```
TargetException: Object does not match target type.
StackTrace:
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.CheckConsistency(Object target)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, 
BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index, CultureInfo culture)
at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, Object[] index)
InnerException: None
```

You can see from the xaml above that I've tried a number of ways to display the `HarwareRevNumMajor` property that lives on a `Device_Info` by the commented out `TextBlock` code.

My ViewModel looks like this:

```
namespace usb_test
{
    public class View_Model
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Device_Info> _devices;
        public ObservableCollection<File_Info> _deviceFiles;
        public CoreDispatcher _dispatcher;
    public View_Model() {
        _devices = new ObservableCollection<Device_Info>();
        _deviceFiles = new ObservableCollection<File_Info>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Device_Info> Devices
    {
        get
        {
            return _devices;
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<File_Info> DeviceFiles
    {
        get
        {
            return _deviceFiles;
        }
    }
```

In My MainPage.xaml.cs I have this:

```
namespace usb_test
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
     Device_List devList = new Device_List();
     Device_Structure deviceStruct = new Device_Structure();
     View_Model viewModel = new View_Model();
     public MainPage()
     {
         this.InitializeComponent();
         viewModel._dispatcher = Dispatcher;
         this.DataContext = viewModel;
         devList.devices.CollectionChanged += this.OnCollectionChanged;
         deviceStruct.deviceFiles.CollectionChanged += this.OnCollectionChanged;
...
```

This line of code is what adds a device to the list:

```
await viewModel._dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async() => { devList.devices.Add(devInfo); });
```

This line succeeds and adds a `Dev_Info` object into the devices observableCollection and shortly after the application crashes.

I'm sure there are more errors when I try to display File Info stuff later in the xaml but I'd really appreciate just getting the pivot header to display correctly. Like I said I'm very new to this so I'm assuming there are a number of problems, I'd appreciate any advice/clarity into what is stopping me from not being able to display a property from a `Dev_Info` object.

Thanks!

Comment: 'Catastrophic failure' is a fairly generic error from the xaml framework. Isolate individual components to try to find out what's failing. Can you bind '<TextBlock Text="{Binding HardwareRevNumMajor}">' successfully to a single Device_Info outside of the observable collection? Does the above xaml work if you comment out the HeaderTemplate? If you comment out the ItemTemplate? Both?

Answer (score 0):

Your items from `Devices` are of type `Device_Info`. In your `DataTemplate` your bind the text property to `Device_Info.HardwareRevNumMajor`. Since the context is your item (Device_Info), you try to access a property Device_Info.

If your write:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding HardwareRevNumMajor}" />
```

You try to access the property `HardwareRevNumMajor` wich probably exists in Device_Info.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Above I pointed out that I had also tried this:         `<!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding HardwareRevNumMajor}">
 </TextBlock>-->` and that also didn't work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You can just test `Text="{Binding}"` to check what your context is.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions above. I made some progress.

I rewrote my xaml like this:

```
<Page
x:Class="usb_test.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:usb_test"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:code="using:usb_test"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Pivot x:Name="pivot1" Title="Pivot" Opacity="0.99" ItemsSource="{x:Bind viewModel.Devices}">
        <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Device_Info">
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind HardwareRevNumMajor}"></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Device_Info">
                <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind devStruct.deviceFiles}" Grid.Row="1">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:File_Info">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{x:Bind fileName}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,20,0"/>
                                <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{x:Bind numBlocks}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,20,0"/>
                                <Button Content="Download File" Click="{x:Bind onDownloadClick}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,20,0">
                                </Button>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Pivot.ItemTemplate>
    </Pivot>
</Grid>
```

You'll notice I took out the

```
<Page.DataContext>
  <local:View_Model/>
</Page.DataContext>
```

from my previous xaml code.

Then I used `ItemsSource="{x:Bind viewModel.Devices}">` in the Pivot. `viewModel` is defined in my MainPage.xaml.cs and is an instance of the `View_Model` class I created above. Then from there I added a `DataType` to `DataTemplate` which is a `Device_Info` and then I could easily access an attribute of the `Device_Info` object, in this case `HardwareRevNumMajor`.

The PivotItemTemplate is a little more confusing. The class `Device_Info` has a property on it called `devStruct` which is a class I created (`Device_Struct`). An instance of `Device_Struct` has an ObservableCollection of `File_Info` objects. So this collection tells us the files on the device and it's called `deviceFiles`. That is the collection I wanted to use inside the Pivot Items. I'm not sure if there's a way to do this without inserting a `<ListView>` into the XAML but this is what I found works. With this I can now display information about the files on each Pivot Item.

I also switched from using `Binding` to `x:Binding`. To be honest I'm not sure exactly why that helped but when I used Binding I was getting: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. If anyone has a better understanding of that, I'd love to hear about it. Thanks again!